# Como abrir e fechar uma janela do browser programaticamente usando comandos bash em ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bash, navegador-de-internet

Tenho um código bash que, ao final de algumas instalações, deve abrir automaticamente uma janela do browser com uma URL (myapp.com) passada como parâmetro. Uma página de configuração do php é apresentada, confirmando que tudo foi instalado corretamente e depois de 30 segundos essa janela deve fechar automaticamente, instalar mais algumas coisas (entre elas laravel) fazer toda a configuração e abrir uma outra janela novamente, mostrando a página inicial do Laravel.

O bash para no processo de abertura do browser e não acaba. Seguindo este [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910174/opening-and-closing-a-process-using-bash), o que tenho até agora é o seguinte código:

```
...
PRJ_URL = 'myapp.com'
...
firefox $PRJ_URL & PID=`jobs -p`& sleep 30s & kill $PID #OK-mostra a página do phpinfo() corretamente
... #instala mais algumas coisas
... #instala Laravel no folder desejado e configura as permissões
firefox $PRJ_URL #OK-mostra a página inicial do Laravel
```

Tudo está funcionando como o esperado. A úica coisa que não consigo fazer é fechar o browser no primeiro processo automaticamente como deveria acontecer com o `kill $PID`.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente sua variável **PID** não está recebendo o id do processo gerado na abertura do browser. É um pouco complicado utilizar o **jobs -p** nessa situação pois ele exibe os processos gerenciados pela sessão atual([veja mais aqui](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html)).

Eu tentaria uma solução um pouco mais simples:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=$1
timeout=$2

sensible-browser $url & pid=$!
sleep $timeout

echo "Killing proccess["$pid"]..."
kill $pid

# installing some stuff

sensible-browser $url
```

Exemplo:

```
./browser.sh https://google.com 5
```